# Ditaa not aligning

Tags: compilation, alignment, diagram

It should be clear to know (for a human) what I want this ditaa-input file to look like

```
/---------------------------\
|           TEST            |
+--------------+------------+
| foo()        | "yuck < 3" |
+--------------+------------+
| bar()        | NEVEREVER! |
+--------------+------------+
| antlioneater | (x>5) || d |
\--------------+------------/
```

[But it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W33U8.png). Look at the less/greater signs. Plus, that is one out-of-shape antlioneater!

What am I doing wrong? I invoked ditaa v0.9 as `ditaa -E -e utf8 test.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditaa parses > and < as arrow heads even if they are not attached to a line ( --> ), hence the weird rendering. It's unfortunate, but that's how it is!

Comment: Thanks for replying! Having not studied ditaa's codebase, is there any place you'd suggest to use for introducing an escape mechanism? Like in  `>, <, ^, v` rendering arrows, `&>, &<, &^, &v` (explicitly) rendering as ">, <, ^, v", `&&` rendering "&"?

Comment: An escaping mechanism introduces the complication of the alignment of lines that contain escaped characters with the ones that don't. Will & render as empty space or will it render as if it wasn't there?

Comment: Leaving "&" the exemplary escape char, I would suggest to render future `A&&B` like the current `A&B`. So no space between "A" and "&" resp. "&" and "B". Instead, add this one char of space to the side of "A&B" which has more whitespace (or split it if "A&B" should be centered). So future `|  A&&B  |` treated like current `|  A&B  |`, while future `| A&&B`, followed by whitespaces or end-of-line treated like current `| A&B`, followed by whitespaces or EOL.

Comment: Also, if it was for me, I'd introduce a command line switch (e.g. `--escape`) for downwards compatibility, to avoid breaking earlier created ditaas incorporating any `&`. Being at it, I'd probably make that switch an option `--escape <char>` so anyone might use the escape character s/he likes most. (Also, I'd probably laugh about the first complaint who used " " as an escape char…)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using another character that looks like it, for example `‹` and `›`.

It's a bit of a trick, but since the output of ditaa is an image anyway, having a visually similar character is usually good enough.

I personally use this to embed HTML markup in my ditaa charts.